# ng-repeat data binding in Angular not working. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple Premier League table using a free football data api. When I console log vm.table, I get all the data I should have for the table to work. Does that mean there is a fault in the html file? I'm a total novice with angular and I'm trying to learn it by making this little app. Can someone point me to where my problem is? The console shows no errors or anything, but it simply doesn't print the data into the table as expected.

this is the html file:

```
<html ng-app="eplApp" lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>EPL Feeder</title>
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller='tableCtrl as table'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="4">English Premier League Table</th></tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Pos</td>
        <td>Team</td>
        <td>Played</td>
        <td>Win</td>
        <td>Draw</td>
        <td>Loss</td>
        <td>GF</td>
        <td>GA</td>
        <td>GD</td>
        <td>Points</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='team in vm.table' ng-class="{top:team.position === 1, cl: (team.position > 1) && (team.position < 5), el:team.position === 5, rel: (team.position > 17)}">
        <td>{{team.position}}</td>
        <td class="flexbox" ng-click="teamView()">
        <img ng-src="{{team.crestURI}}" alt="{{team.teamName}} crest" />
        <p class="teamName">{{team.teamName}}</p>
        </td>
        <td><p>{{team.playedGames}}</p></td>
        <td>{{team.wins}}</td>
        <td>{{team.draws}}</td>
        <td>{{team.losses}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goals}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalsAgainst}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalDifference}}</td>
        <td>{{team.points}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is the script file:

```
var app = angular.module('eplApp', []);

app.controller('tableCtrl', function($http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.table = [];
    $http({
      headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '971acba677654cdb919a7ccebd5621e2' },
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426/leagueTable"
}).then(function(response) {
  vm.table = response.data.standing;
  console.log(vm.table);
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change,

**From**

```
<body ng-controller='tableCtrl as table'>
```

**To**

```
<body ng-controller='tableCtrl as vm'>
```

Comment: but you better change the vm with your controller name in the binding

Answer (score 1):

it should be similar to this because you use `controllerAs` syntax in your app.

```
 <tr ng-repeat='team in table.standing' ...
```

**Edit**

after editing your question you should use @Sajeetharan answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have indeed used @Sajeetharan's answer. Appreciate the answer all the same. :)